# What does *remediable* mean to philosophers? (Example and context provided)

Tags: logic

In his essay, Knowledge of Logic, Paul Boghossian writes

> Finally, on the inferential path, there is the question whether it is **irremediably** true that rule‐circular arguments provide no justification.

(Emphasis mine.)

Is there a precise philosophical definition of the sense of *irremediably* that Boghossian used in the quote?

Comment: not really sure here cos idk what "rule-circular" means, but without that bit  what i'd read irremediably as would be: the opponent arguing otherwise is a flake. mind you, i always read the term as "irredeemable" - i think !

Comment: I'm not aware of such a technical term. It seems to me an informal term.

Comment: Probably something similar to what it means to carpenters, accountants and taxi drivers.